# Permission denied on shutil.move on image files

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to move some files around. I can move any extension type except .png, .jpg, or .gif. When I try to move those types of files I get "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" even though I am the admin. Code below

```
import os, glob, shutil
dir = r'C:\\Users\\jcan4\\Desktop\\testmove\\*'
print(dir)
files = glob.glob(dir)
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)


for i, file in enumerate(files, start=1):
    print(file)
    oldext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    shutil.move(file,  'Attachment-%s' % (i) + oldext)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First things first**, you're double escaping your `dir` variable:

```py
print(r'C:\\Users\\jcan4\\Desktop\\testmove\\*')
# Yields 'C:\\\\Users\\\\jcan4\\\\Desktop\\\\testmove\\\\*' !!

# What you really meant was either one of the following:
dir_harderToRead = 'C:\\Users\\jcan4\\Desktop\\testmove\\*'
dir_easyToRead = r'C:\Users\jcan4\Desktop\testmove\*'
```

**If you are still experiencing the error**, it's because you are not giving the *python script* permissions to move the file. There are a couple ways to get around this:

### Windows

(This applies to the asked question)

1. Open command prompt (I see your file path and am assuming you're on windows) with administrative rights. ([see here](https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/))
2. Change ownership of the images to you. (see [here for windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-take-ownership-files-and-folders-windows-10) or [here for windows 7](https://gilsmethod.com/how-to-change-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows-7))

### Linux (MacOS)

(This applies to people on Linux that may have the same problem)

1. Run the python script with root privileges:

```sh
# At command line
sudo python your_script_name.py
```

2. Change ownership of file to yourself:

```sh
# At command line
# Changes ownership of entire directory (CAREFUL):
chmod 755 /absolute/path/to/dir
chmod 755 relative/path/to/dir

# Or you can change file by file:
chmod 755 /absolute/path/to/file
chmod 755 relative/path/to/file
```

For more info, I used [this site](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/checking-linux-file-permissions-with-ls/) on permissions. (If someone has a numerical value than `755` for chmod please say so.)

Comment: This was it! Thank you, so much!

Comment: `sudo chmod 755 /absolute/path/to/dir;sudo chmod 755 relative/path/to/dir` and it's better to say "`sudo python` will run python without virtual environment "; anyway, thanks for your solution