# shutil.move() to network drive permission denied

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, shutil

I am attempting to write a simple python script to move files as they come into a folder in ubuntu.

I'm moving the files from my local machine to my network ubuntu machine.

See code below:

```
        files_in_staging = os.listdir(staging_dir)
        
        time.sleep(10)
        print(files_in_staging)

        if len(files_in_staging) > 0:
            print('files found in staging')
            time.sleep(1)

            for each in files_in_staging:
                print('moving '+each)
                shutil.move(staging_dir + each, target + each)
```

When running the script directly, I'm given error 95.

When running the script with sudo I'm given a PermissionError. I have tried setting os.uid to the user to no avail.

Is there any way to provide a password + username for permisson?

Copy pasting the files goes without a hitch

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135027/permission-denied-on-shutil-move-on-image-files

Comment: You have to get read/write permission when you mount the SMB drive.  If you don't have r/w permission by the time you run your script, it's too late.  And `sudo` doesn't have any effect on SMB permissions.  They are all determined at mount time.

Comment: Does the SMB drive need to be mounted by the python script? When I move a file in nautilus it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the pathnames is wrong, not:

```
shutil.move(staging_dir + each, target + each)
```

but:

```
shutil.move(
    os.path.join( staging_dir, each ),
    os.path.join( target, each )
)
```

Comment: The path is not the problem, it's the permissions related to SMB and python.